# Start process, hide arguments from ps

Tags: php, python, security

I have a Python script that interfaces with an API. The script is started from a PHP page. I wrote both scripts, so I can change the code in either as appropriate.

The Python script needs a username and password to interface with the API. My first inclination is to pass them to Python as CLI arguments:

```
<?php
exec('python someScript.py AzureDiamond hunter2');
?>
```

However, anybody can then see the credentials via `ps`:

```
$ ps | grep someScript
1000     23295  2.0  0.2 116852  9252 pts/0    S+   15:47   0:00 python someScript.py AzureDiamond hunter2
```

Alternatives that I am considering are to write the data to a text file or sqlite database, then to delete them. Are there any better ideas? A constraint with the sqlite approach is that this needs to run in a rather portable fashion (phpFox Plugin) and most budget webhosts don't support the `sqlite3` module.

Comment: You can pass it via pipes perhaps. See also proc_open() to set environment variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use environment variables which you set in PHP and read in the Python script.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. How secure is that from other users running on the system, and how secure from other processes running as the same user (user `nobody` because Apache started it)? How long after the PHP script dies will the environment variable persist, if the Python script fails to load in order to overwrite it?

Comment: Partial answer: it's not secure from other processes running as the same user: they can read /proc/$PID/environ.

Comment: In case you are on a Linux OS you can set the environment variable just for the shell that executes the python interpreter using something like `exec("USERNAME=paul PASSWORD=mypw python script.py")` those would not be set in the environment of the php process. As Anton says, the environment is still visible to the same user for the time the python process is running.

Comment: Thank you, this is a terrific, creative solution.

Answer (score 1):

The proposed methods are a security problem waiting to happen. MyProxy is a secure way to handle private keys or certificates. MyProxy might not be the particular solution you need, but these types of solutions are what you need to be looking at.

http://grid.ncsa.illinois.edu/myproxy/

Answer (score 1):

You could use stdin in the python process to read the parameters, and open the process like this from php:

```
<?php
$handle = popen("/bin/python /var/www/someScript.py", "w");
// write username and password to $handle (e.g. newline separated)
?>
```

I don't know how secure this is against other processes running as the same user (could it by hijacked from /proc/nn/fd/0 ?), but it certainly makes it harder than just looking at the process list.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the problem from another angle, it could be solved if you hide the plain characters being passed to exec(). Have you considered using any cryptograhic lib to hide plain text from the sender and decrypt in the receiver? Just a thought.